# Measure theoretic integral notation

Tags: integration, measure-theory

Is there a difference between the following

$\int_A \int_B F(dx,dy)$ and $\int_{A\times B}F(dx,dy)$

If there is not, is one preferred over the other?

Comment: The function $f(x, y)=\frac{x^2-y^2}{(x^2+y^2)^2}$ has $\int \int f(x, y)dxdy=\pi/4$, but $\int \int f(x, y)dydx=-\pi/4$. Since $\int_{A\times B}f(x, y)dx\times dy$ is manifestly symmetric, this shows they cannot coincide. However, if $\int_{A\times B} |f(x, y)|dx\times dy<\infty$,  then they coincide by Fubini's theorem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, I haven't come across any of the two, rather I have seen $\int_A\int_B F(x,y) \, dx \, dy $ or $ \int_{A\times B} F(x,y) \,dx \,dy $

Then, in fact, these are different things. The first is an integral of the function $\int_B F(x, y) dy $ over $A$ (which may or may not be defined and integrable), while the second is an integral in the product space $A\times B$. The pertinent theorem which says when the first is well defined and may equal the second is Fubinis' theorem. (And, since these are different things, it does not make sense to 'prefer' any of them).

Comment: The second is an integral in the product space but $x\in A$ and $y\in B$, correct? That's what's confusing me.

Comment: @ToniAz Yes, that's right, but with the constraint $(x,y)\in A\times B$.

Comment: if $x\in A$ and $y\in B$, doesn't this imply that $(x,y)\in A\times B$ is automatically satisfied?

Comment: @ToniAz yes, my bad.